# Number of ways from top of the black square on chess board to any bottom black square when moving downwards diagonally to black squares only.

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

I have attempted this problem by drawing out grid like this:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline1&&1&&1&&1&\\\hline&2&&2&&2&&1\\\hline2&&4&&4&&3&\\\hline&6&&8&&7&&3\\\hline6&&14&&15&&10&\\\hline&20&&29&&25&&10\\\hline20&&49&&54&&35&\\\hline&69&&103&&89&&35\\\hline
\end{array}
This gives me $69+103+89+35=296$ $ways$.
However this method is obviously long and will not be applicable for bigger grids like 20×20 so is there a more systematic way to solve this using combinatorics. 
 So far i have tried something like : $4$ ways to choose black square on top row. Then $(4×2)-1=7$ ways for choosing a black square on second row (I subtracted $1$ because one of the black square don't lead to 2 black squares but one). Similarly, $(7×2)-1=13$ ways to choose on third row. But for forth row it should be (according to the way I am going) $(13×2)-1=25$ ways but there are 24 ways. So my method stops working.
What would be the way to go about in this question?

Comment: Your recurrence should subtract the end number of the row, so for the fourth row the sum will be $(2 \times 13)-2=24$ and for the fifth $(2 \times 24)-3=45$.  That means you need to keep track of the end number of the row.  I don't yet have a suggestion there.

Comment: Why do you think that $20\times 20$ would be difficult?  The same induction works just fine.

Comment: But that would require me to find the end number so for bigger grids I would have to find every end number. Is there no other way?

Comment: @lulu could be please elaborate on what do you mean by reverse induction?

Comment: The end values seem to be ${n \choose \lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor}$ given in http://oeis.org/A001405.  If you can justify that you are home.  The notes talk of Dyck paths which are what you need,  I think.

Comment: Start at the bottom.  Put $1's$ in the black squares, and $0's$ in the white squares.  Then go up recursively:  The content of each cell is the sum of the contents of the cells diagonally beneath it (it being understood that all cells out of the grid contain $0$).  Then sum the top row.  $20\times 20$ is instantaneous.

Comment: $20\times 20$ is still extremely small. Where is the difficulty ?

Comment: "Instantaneous" on a computer, sure, but it sounds like OP is asking for a faster way to compute the answer by hand. Ross Millikan's comments are helpful.

Comment: Thanks, @Karl. I am doing this by hand and I have to generalise this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of diagonal paths from any black square on the top row of a $2n\times 2n$ chessboard to any black square on the bottom row is in OEIS: https://oeis.org/A153336. They give the formula
$$
(2n+1)2^{2n-2}-(4n-2)\binom{2n-2}{n-1}.
$$
When $n=4$, this indeed evaluates to $296$.